# Как вообще пользоваться этим ForkJoinPool(ом)?

Tags: java

Создал два метода для вычисления чисел Фибоначчи: один с обычной рекурсией, а другой с `ForkJoinPool(ом)`. Проблема в том, что метод `fibonacci1` в разы, если не в сотни раз, быстрее метода `fibonacci`. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему. Как вообще правильно пользоваться `ForkJoinPool(ом)`?

```java
public class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveTask<Long> {

    private static ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long l1, l2;
        l1 = System.nanoTime();
        fibonacci1(40);
        l2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(l2 - l1);
        l1 = System.nanoTime();
        fibonacci(40);
        l2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(l2 - l1);
    }

    private long n;

    private MyRecursiveAction(long n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public static long fibonacci(long n) {
        return forkJoinPool.invoke(new MyRecursiveAction(n));
//        return new MyRecursiveAction(n).invoke();
    }

    public static long fibonacci1(long n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            return n;
        if (n > 0)
            return fibonacci1(n - 1) + fibonacci1(n - 2);
        else
            return fibonacci1(n + 2) - fibonacci1(n + 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            return n;
        if (n > 0) {
            MyRecursiveAction myRecursiveAction1 = new MyRecursiveAction(n - 1);
            forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveAction1);
//            myRecursiveAction1.fork();
            MyRecursiveAction myRecursiveAction2 = new MyRecursiveAction(n - 2);
            forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveAction2);
//            myRecursiveAction2.fork();
//            return myRecursiveAction1.join() + myRecursiveAction2.join();
            return myRecursiveAction1.join() + myRecursiveAction2.join();
        } else {
            MyRecursiveAction myRecursiveAction1 = new MyRecursiveAction(n + 1);
            forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveAction1);
//            myRecursiveAction1.fork();
            MyRecursiveAction myRecursiveAction2 = new MyRecursiveAction(n + 2);
            forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveAction2);
//            myRecursiveAction2.fork();
//            return myRecursiveAction2.join() - myRecursiveAction1.join();
            return myRecursiveAction2.join() - myRecursiveAction1.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все `ExecutorService` предназначены для выполнения относительно тяжеловесных задач в выделенных потоках. Ими можно пользоваться, например, при обработке фото - разбить фотографию на `n` областей и загрузить их в `n` потоков, а потом объединить результат. На многоядерных процессорах, скорее всего, ускорение обработки будет в `n` раз, так как потоки будут работать на выделенных ядрах. Или можно сделать обработку запросов в веб-сервисе: диспетчер получает запрос и отдаёт его в пул на обработку; когда в пуле освободится поток, он подхватит запрос и приступит к вычислениям. Если вычисления гораздо тяжелее, чем накладные расходы на порождение потоков, диспетчеризацию потоков, ожидание завершения потоков, то использование пула заметно прибавит производительности по сравнению с однопоточным выполнение.

Но в вашем случае операция сложения настолько легковесна, что накладные расходы на работу с пулом многократно превышают затраты на собственно вычисления.

UPD

## Пример: поиск делителей

Для примера запустим параллельный поиск делителей целого числа. У алгоритма поиска есть два параметра - максимальная длина интервала для перебора и число порождаемых подзадач.

Если интервал поиска делителей, назначенный задаче, слишком велик, т.е. `(b-a) > intervalLength`, то задача порождает несколько подзадач, для каждой нарезая уменьшенные интервалы.

То есть одна задача в конечном итоге порождает целое дерево подзадач. Чтобы не перебирать всё, когда делитель уже найден, каждая задача получает экземпляр класса `StopFlag` с булевским флагом. Подзадача, нашедшая делитель, поднимает этот флаг, и все остальные подзадачи ничего не считают.

Подзадачи запускаются вызовом `task.fork()` - этот метод ставит подзадачу на исполнение в тот же пул, который использовался для запуска родительской задачи.

Сразу скажу - пример дурацкий, исключительно для иллюстрации распараллеливания.

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Divisors extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    private long n;
    private long a;
    private long b;
    private int forkFactor ;
    private long length;
    private StopFlag stopFlag;

    protected static class StopFlag {
        public boolean done = false;
        public boolean isDone() {
            return done;
        }
    }
    
    public Divisors(long n, long a, long b, int forkFactor, long length, StopFlag stopFlag) {
        this.n = n;
        if (0 == a % 2) {
            a += 1;
        }
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.forkFactor = forkFactor;
        this.length = length;
        
        if (stopFlag == null) {
            this.stopFlag = new StopFlag();
        } else {
            this.stopFlag = stopFlag;
        }
    }

    public Divisors(long n, long a, long b, int forkFactor, long length) {
        this(n,a,b,forkFactor, length, null);
    }

    protected Long compute() {
        // System.out.println("Compute started, thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if (stopFlag.isDone()) {
            return 0L;
        }
        if ((b - a) < length) {
            // Interval is short enough to do the brute force search
            return bruteForce();
        } else {
            // Split the interval and start subtasks
            return divideAndConquer();
        }
    }

    private Long divideAndConquer() {
        ArrayList<ForkJoinTask<Long>> results = new ArrayList<ForkJoinTask<Long>>();
        long step = (b-a)/forkFactor + 1;
        for (long i = a; i < b; i+= step) {
            ForkJoinTask<Long> task = new Divisors(n, i, i+step, forkFactor, length, stopFlag);
            results.add(task.fork());
        }
        for (ForkJoinTask<Long> result : results) {
            long divisor = result.join();
            if (divisor > 0) {
                return divisor;
            }
        }
        return 0L;
    }

    private Long bruteForce() {
        for (long i = a; i <= b; i += 2) {
            long res = n % i;
            if (res == 0) {
                System.out.println("Found");
                stopFlag.done = true;
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

К этой задаче приделан вот такой пускач:

```java
package org.example;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;

public class MainDivisors {

    /**
     * if {@code (b-a) > intervalLength} then fork the task into {@code forkFactor} subtasks
     */
    private static final long intervalLength = 10000000L;
    private static int forkFactor = 4;
    private static ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(forkFactor);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long t1, t2;
        
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(32, new Random());
        BigInteger q = p.nextProbablePrime();
        long n = p.longValue()*q.longValue();
        
        System.out.println("Factoring " + n + " = " + p + "*" + q);
        
        System.out.println("Single thread");
        {
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            long result = divisorSingleThread(n);
            t2 = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Divisor: " + result + ", time: " + (t2 - t1));
        }
        System.out.println("Pool");
        {
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            long result = divisorPooled(n, forkFactor, intervalLength);
            t2 = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Divisor: " + result + ", time: " + (t2 - t1));
        }
    }

    public static Long divisorPooled(long n, int forkFactor, long intervalLength) {
        if (n %2 == 0) {
            return 2L;
        }
        long a = 3;
        long b = (long) (Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))) + 1;

        ForkJoinTask<Long> task = new Divisors(n, a, b, forkFactor, intervalLength);
        ForkJoinTask<Long> result = forkJoinPool.submit(task);
        return result.join();
    }

    public static Long divisorSingleThread(long n) {
        if (n %2 == 0) {
            return 2L;
        }
        long a = 3;
        long b = (long) (Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))) + 1;
        for (long i = a; i < b; i += 2) {
            long res = n % i;
            if (res == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0L;
    }

}
```

Как показали испытания, ускорение в 2-3 раза. Пример высосан из пальца, и накладные расходы на организацию параллельности сопоставимы с выигрышем производительности, но зато демонстрирует основные идеи MapReduce:

- разбиение проблемного пространства (partition),
- применение вычислительной функции к полученным слайсам (map),
- сведение результатов от разных партиций (reduce).

UPD2

## Правильный пример

Несмотря на то, что автор вопроса уже принял мой ответ, я таки его расширю и дополню - покажу *правильный* пример. Пример, приведённый выше, равно как и [пример в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html) неверны.

Проблема обоих примеров в том, что задача, поставленная в пул, порождает подзадачи и **ждёт их завершения**. То есть один из потоков пула блокируется. При наличии заблокированных потоков пул создаёт новые потоки для решения задач, что стоит отнюдь не копейки.

*Правильное* решение должно разделять map и reduce. Map делается в одном месте, а reduce в другом. Не нужно ничего ждать. После порождения подзадач работа родительской задачи завершается, чтобы освободить ресурс. Результат работы порожденных задач должен обрабатываться в другом месте.

Чтобы передавать поменьше параметров в задачу, я сгруппировал их в два класса. `Interval` задаёт интервал перебора делителей.

```java
package org.example;

public class Interval {
    public final long a;
    public final long b;

    public Interval(long a, long b) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public long length() {
        return b - a;
    }
}
```

Полностью асинхронное решение требует две вещи: общее хранилище для результата и примитив синхронизации для сигнала, что все задачи завершены и решение сформировано.

Для хранения результата в Java есть класс `CompletableFuture<Long>`. Метод `isDone` говорит, что результат готов, метод `get` позволяет результат получить, метод `join` блокирует вызывающий поток до тех пор, пока результат не будет готов. Результат устанавливается методом `complete`, который сохраняет результат внутри, взводит `isDone` и разблокирует ожидание `join`. Там есть ещё много что, но для примера достаточно.

Для подсчета числа завершенных задач я использовал примитив `Phaser`. Он содержит внутренний счетчик активных участников, который можно увеличивать вызовами метода `bulkRegister`, и уменьшать вызовами `arriveAndDeregister`. Обнуления счетчика можно ждать методом `awaitAdvance`. В фазере есть ещё функционал, но для управления задачами поиска делителя достаточно этого. Для простоты я обернул эти функции в класс `CountLock`:

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;

public class CountLock {
    private final Phaser lock;
    private int phase;

    public CountLock() {
        lock = new Phaser();
        phase = lock.getPhase();
    }
    
    public void addTasks(int count) {
        lock.bulkRegister(count);
    }
    
    public void completeTask() {
        lock.arriveAndDeregister();
    }
    
    public void await() {
        lock.awaitAdvance(phase);
    }
}
```

Параметры процесса решения - максимальный интервал перебора, число порождаемых подзадач, счетчик активных задач и хранилище ожидаемого результата, - я убрал в отдельный класс `Params`. Чисто для эстетики - не люблю длинные цепочки параметров в вызовах.

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Params {
    public final int forkFactor;
    public final long maxInterval;
    public final CompletableFuture<Long> result;

    public final CountLock lock;

    public Params(int forkFactor, long maxInterval, CountLock lock, CompletableFuture<Long> result) {
        super();
        this.forkFactor = forkFactor;
        this.maxInterval = maxInterval;
        this.result = result;
        
        this.lock = lock;
    }
}
```

Все приготовления сделаны, можно готовить.

Так как результат теперь хранится в отдельном месте, то тип изменён с `RecursiveTask<V>` на `RecursiveAction`.

```
package org.example;

import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Divisors extends RecursiveAction {
    private long n;
    private Interval interval;
    private Params params;

    public Divisors(long n, Interval i, Params params) {
        this.n = n;
        this.params = params;
        this.interval = i;
    }

    protected void compute() {
        try {
            if (params.result.isDone()) {
                return;
            }
            if (interval.length() < params.maxInterval) {
                // Interval is short enough to do the brute force search
                bruteForce();
            } else {
                // Split the interval and start subtasks
                divideAndConquer();
            }
        } finally {
            params.lock.completeTask();
        }
    }

    private void divideAndConquer() {
        long step = interval.length() / params.forkFactor + 1;
        params.lock.addTasks(params.forkFactor);

        for (long i = interval.a; i < interval.b; i += step) {
            RecursiveAction task = new Divisors(n, new Interval(i, i + step), params);
            task.fork();
        }
    }

    private void bruteForce() {
        long a = interval.a;
        if (0 == a % 2) {
            a += 1;
        }
        long b = interval.b;

        for (long i = a; i <= b; i += 2) {
            long res = n % i;
            if (res == 0) {
                System.out.println("Found: " + i);
                params.result.complete(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Более чем 10-кратный прирост скорости прячется внутри новой организации методов `bruteForce`, `compute` и `divideAndConquer`.

`bruteForce` теперь не возвращает результат, а сохраняет его в общее хранилище, заодно взводя флаг о завершении процесса счёта: `params.result.complete(i)`.

`divideAndConquer` бьет задачи на подзадачи и увеличивает счётчик активных задач: `params.lock.addTasks(params.forkFactor);` Обратите внимание, счётчик увеличивается *до того* как задачи ставятся на исполнение, иначе можно влететь в race condition - в порождённой задаче `complete` будет вызван до того, как в порождающей `addTasks`.

`compute` при завершении уменьшает счетчик задач на единицу:

```
        try {
            // ...
        } finally {
            params.lock.completeTask();
        }
```

Тест производительности. У меня четырехядерный процессор с восемью физическими потоками, поэтому я задал размер пула равным семи. Performance monitor показывает загрузку всех ядер, то есть пул успешно распараллелил задачу, и ядра на 100% заняты счётом - никто никого не ждёт.

Одна задача перебирает в интервале не длиннее одного миллиона. Варьирование этого параметра может повлиять на производительность - если поставить слишком маленький интервал, накладные затраты на переключение задач будут выше затрат на счёт. Если поставить слишком большим, то максимум параллельности достигнут не будет.

```java
package org.example;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class MainDivisors {

    /**
     * if {@code (b-a) > intervalLength} then fork the task into {@code forkFactor} subtasks
     */
    private static final long intervalLength = 1000000L;
    private static int forkFactor = 7;
    private static ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(forkFactor);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long t1, t2;
        
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(31, new Random());
        BigInteger q = p.nextProbablePrime();
        long n = p.longValue()*q.longValue();      
        System.out.println("Factoring " + n + " = " + p + "*" + q);
        
        // long n = 2130663859L*2130663869L; // 4539728501355410471 
        // System.out.println("Factoring " + n + " = 2130663859L*2130663869");

        System.out.println("Single thread");
        {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            long result = divisorSingleThread(n);
            t1 = System.nanoTime() - start;
            System.out.println("Divisor: " + result + ", time: " + t1);
        }
        System.out.println("Pool");
        {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            long result = divisorPooled(n, forkFactor, intervalLength);
            t2 = System.nanoTime() - start;
            System.out.println("Divisor: " + result + ", time: " + t2);
        }
        System.out.println("Speed up " + ((double)t1)/t2 + " times");
    }

    public static Long divisorPooled(long n, int forkFactor, long intervalLength) {
        if (n %2 == 0) {
            return 2L;
        }
        long a = 3;
        long b = (long) (Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))) + 1;
        
        CountLock lock = new CountLock();
        CompletableFuture<Long> result = new CompletableFuture<Long>();

        Params params = new Params(forkFactor, intervalLength, lock, result);
        
        RecursiveAction task = new Divisors(n, new Interval(a, b), params);
        lock.addTasks(1);
        
        forkJoinPool.submit(task);
        lock.await();
        
        if (result.isDone()) {
            return result.join();
        } else {
            return 0L;
        }
    }

    public static Long divisorSingleThread(long n) {
        if (n %2 == 0) {
            return 2L;
        }
        long a = 3;
        long b = (long) (Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))) + 1;
        for (long i = a; i < b; i += 2) {
            long res = n % i;
            if (res == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0L;
    }

}
```

Тест раскладывает на множители 62-х битное число: произведение двух случайных 31-битных простых. То есть нужно перебрать порядка миллиарда вариантов.

При разложении числа `4539728501355410471 = 2130663859*2130663869` поиск делителей в цикле находит делитель за 8-11 секунд. Не могу сказать, откуда такой разброс берётся. Какие-то фокусы планировщика Windows или JIT компилятора Java.

Параллельный алгоритм находит делитель за 0.04 - 0.06 секунд. Ускорение в среднем в 200 раз. Это не опечатка, **двести** раз.

```
Factoring 4539728501355410471 = 2130663859L*2130663869
Single thread
Divisor: 2130663859, time: 10414989800
Pool
Found: 2130663859
Divisor: 2130663859, time: 48492800
Speed up 214.77394169856143 times
```

### Обсуждение

Объясняется такой выигрыш просто. По умолчанию `ForkJoinPool` использует стек для хранения задач, поступивших на счёт. То есть последние выполняются первыми, и в нашем случае счёт начинается с конца. Так как тестовое число есть произведение двух больших сомножителей, то его находят практически сразу.

Если же в качестве теста взять произведение трёх 20-битных сомножителей, то лобовой перебор побеждает с разгромным счётом. Тоже в двести раз быстрее ))

Если снова вернуться к произведению двух больших сомножителей, и убрать оптимизацию, прекращающую счёт в задачах, когда найден ответ, то ускорение будет в 2-2.5 раз. Разброс вызван тем, что время счёта в цикле варьируется от 8.5 до 11 секунд, а параллельный счёт всегда считает за 4.5 секунд.

Comment: То есть в целом всё правильно написано? Просто сначала вместо `forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveAction1)` я писал `myRecursiveAction1.fork()`. Чем отличаются эти способы? И с помощью `ForkJoinPool(а)` я пытался ограничить количество используемых потоков, но, кажется, не получилось.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Количество физических потоков действительно ограничено. `commonPool` инцициализируется с каким-то минимальным числом потоков, добавляя новые по мере удлиннения очереди запросов. `invoke` запускает задачу и ждёт её завершения, поэтому такой вызов вообще не даёт никаких бонусов )
Нужно делать в цикле `task.fork()` или `pool.submit(task)`, поставив все задачи в очередь, а затем в другом цикле вызывать `task.join()`, чтобы дождаться завершения задач и получить результаты.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия добавил пример, чтобы показать выигрыш на тяжеловесной задаче.

Comment: В примере вы используете `pool.submit(task)`. Я так понимаю, что если использовать `task.fork()`, то никакого ограничения на количество потоков накладываться не будет. Так?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия простите, не понял. Если число потоков в пуле будет больше числа ядер процессора, то потоки будут конкурировать за вычислительную мощь. Я использую `submit`, чтобы явно показать, какой пул использовать для вычислений. `task.fork()` [отправит в пул `ForkJoinPool.commonPool`](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.java#L696), либо, если код выполняется в контексте одного из рабочих потоков пула, в этот же самый пул.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, я обновил пример - добавил в него вызов `fork`. Теперь задача сама себя делит на подзадачи, если интервал перебора слишком велик. Подзадачи запускаются вызовом `fork`.